# Module imap.ini missing PHP Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, email, postfix

When I execute the command: `phpenmod imap`, the output is:

```
WARNING: Module imap ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available
```

I executed `apt-cache search php7`. The following is displayed:

```
php7.1-imap - IMAP module for php
```

I also executed `apt-cache search libcc`. I find that `libc-client2007 -c-client` library for mail protocols is present.

What steps should I take to enable/activate the PHP IMAP module?

Answer (score 1):

You have not installed the `php-imap` package correctly.

Prior installing, ensure that your system is upgraded and all dependencies are resolved:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Run the following commands to install and enable it for Ubuntu 16.04 or later:

```
sudo apt-get install php-imap
sudo phpenmod imap
```

To install and enable it for Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imap
sudo php5enmod imap
```

Comment: Your commands were executed prior to the warning error. In fact, if I execute your commands, I get:  "Php-imap is already the newest version (1:7.1+54ubuntu1)". If I execute, phpenmod imap, I get the warning that the module imap ini does not exist. When I run dpkg --get-selections | grep php-imap, I get "php-imap  install". Now, when dpkg -L php-imap is xecuted to find the location, I get /usr/share/doc/php7.1-imap/....Seven gz files can be seen with all the README files. My understand is that imap must be compiled manually. Thanks for your feed back.

Comment: @Nene 1. What Ubuntu version are you using? 2. There is no good reason why it should need to be compiled. I have edited my answer. Please try the new answer.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. There is no need to compile anything. I have solved the problem with a symbolic link and added the imap.so in the php.ini. I also added two files: 20-imap.ini in cli and apache2.  Testing was posivite. It works like a charm now.